# How to use Checkbox in ListView with JSON data

Tags: android, json, listview, checkbox, android-adapter

I'm newbie Android developer. I want to someone help me.
Now, I can call JSON data to my ListView. I did to import checkbox in to ListView. But It's not work. When i am selected on some checkbox just will have other checkbox are selected such as below example event.

checkbox      name

X              A

_              B

_              C

_              D

_              E

_              F

__________________  << bottom screen

X              G

_              H

_              I

When i am selected checkbox "A". Just will has another one checkbox was selected too (checkbox G).

1. I need to know how to resolve this case.
2. How to do if i want to show all checkbox are selected after click button submit.

Sorry for my bad English language skill.
Please help me sir.

SearchActivity.java

```html
package com.example.rattapongt.rjp_b;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.rattapongt.rjp_b.Date.myCalendarView;
import com.example.rattapongt.rjp_b.Util.Config;
import com.example.rattapongt.rjp_b.Util.RequestHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ProgressDialog loading;
    private String JSON_STRING;

    ListView listView;
    TextView tvDate, tvDateHide;
    EditText editTextId, editTextId2;
    ImageView ivSearch;
    Button btnDate, btnReject;

    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    private String mYearCheck;

    static final int CALENDAR_VIEW_ID = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
        editTextId2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId2);

        ivSearch = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivSearch);

        tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        tvDateHide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDateHide);

        btnDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
        btnReject = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReject);

        ivSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnReject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, RejectActivity.class);
                //startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        editTextId.setText("1992");
        editTextId2.setText("PCB116A731 ");

        // add a click listener to the button
        btnDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, myCalendarView.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CALENDAR_VIEW_ID);

            }
        });


    }


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case CALENDAR_VIEW_ID:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                    tvDate.setText(bundle.getString("dateSelected1"));
                    tvDateHide.setText(bundle.getString("dateSelected"));
                    break;
                }
        }
    }



    private void getJSON() {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(SearchActivity.this, "Fetching Data", "Wait...", false, false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_STRING = s;

              showEmployee();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL);

                return s;
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();

    }


    private void showEmployee() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String Ta = jo.getString(Config.TAG_A);
                String Tb = jo.getString(Config.TAG_B);
                String Tc = jo.getString(Config.TAG_C);
                String Td = jo.getString(Config.TAG_D);
                String Te = jo.getString(Config.TAG_E);
                String Tf = jo.getString(Config.TAG_F);
                String Tg = jo.getString(Config.TAG_G);


                HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                employees.put(Config.TAG_A, Ta);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_B, Tb);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_C, Tc);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_D, Td);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_E, Te);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_F, Tf);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_G, Tg);

                list.add(employees);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                SearchActivity.this, list, R.layout.item_list,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_A, Config.TAG_B, Config.TAG_C, Config.TAG_D, Config.TAG_E, Config.TAG_F, Config.TAG_G},
                new int[]{R.id.invoiceNo, R.id.code, R.id.name, R.id.itemNo, R.id.poNo, R.id.sq, R.id.qty});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void getData() {

        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Fetching...", false, false);

        //String url = Config.DATA_URL + editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
        String url = Config.DATA_URL + "&strKeyword=" + editTextId.getText().toString().trim()
                + "&strKeyword3=" + tvDateHide.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loading.dismiss();
                        lostConnection();

                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }



    private void showJSON(String response) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObjectSearch = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObjectSearch.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

            //For map values for JSON to android
            /*
            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
            name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
            vc = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);
            */

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String Ka = jo.getString(Config.TAG_A);
                String Kb = jo.getString(Config.TAG_B);
                String Kc = jo.getString(Config.TAG_C);
                String Kd = jo.getString(Config.TAG_D);
                String Ke = jo.getString(Config.TAG_E);
                String Kf = jo.getString(Config.TAG_F);
                String Kg = jo.getString(Config.TAG_G);

                HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                employees.put(Config.TAG_A, Ka);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_B, Kb);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_C, Kc);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_D, Kd);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_E, Ke);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_F, Kf);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_G, Kg);
                list.add(employees);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //That will be show information to textView.
        /*
        if (!name.toString().equals("null")) {
            //textViewResult.setText("Name:\t" + name + "\nDesignation:\t" + address + "\nSalary:\t" + vc);
            Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            textViewResult.setText("Data not found!");
        }
        //textViewResult.setText("Name:\t" + name + "\nDesignation:\t" + address + "\nSalary:\t" + vc);
*/

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                SearchActivity.this, list, R.layout.item_list,
                new String[]{Config.KEY_A, Config.KEY_B, Config.KEY_C, Config.KEY_D, Config.KEY_E, Config.KEY_F, Config.KEY_G},
                new int[]{R.id.invoiceNo, R.id.code, R.id.name, R.id.itemNo, R.id.poNo, R.id.sq, R.id.qty});

        //Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }



   

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```html
package com.example.rattapongt.rjp_b.Util;

/**
 * Created by Rattapongt on 2/23/2017.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.rattapongt.rjp_b.R;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext;
    String[] strName;
    String[] strName1;
    String[] strName2;
    String[] strName3;
    String[] strName4;
    String[] strName5;
    String[] strName6;
    int[] resId;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] strName, String[] strName1, String[] strName2, String[] strName3, String[] strName4, String[] strName5, String[] strName6) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.strName = strName;
        this.strName1 = strName1;
        this.strName2 = strName2;
        this.strName3 = strName3;
        this.strName4 = strName4;
        this.strName5 = strName5;
        this.strName6 = strName6;
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return strName.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (view == null)
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(strName[position]);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView1.setText(strName1[position]);

        TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2.setText(strName2[position]);

        TextView textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView3.setText(strName3[position]);

        TextView textView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView4.setText(strName4[position]);

        TextView textView5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        textView5.setText(strName5[position]);

        TextView textView6 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        textView6.setText(strName6[position]);


        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the position of selected checkbox and store it in arraylist and then compare the position with the selected position list in getView method. If the list is having that position set the checkbox checked else make it uncheck.

Answer (score 0):

I think removing if(view==null) will do the job.Try it , like in the code below:

```
   @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
     LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_parent_cat_individual_items, null);


      TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(strName[position]);

            TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView1.setText(strName1[position]);

            TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView2.setText(strName2[position]);

            TextView textView3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            textView3.setText(strName3[position]);

            TextView textView4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            textView4.setText(strName4[position]);

            TextView textView5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            textView5.setText(strName5[position]);

            TextView textView6 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
            textView6.setText(strName6[position]);


            return view;
        }
```